# How to remove/Customize OptionsPanelController from NetBeans platform?

Tags: java, netbeans, settings, customization

I want to remove some OptionsPanel (Apperance, Miscelaneous) from the Options dialog of NetBeans platform.

How can I customize them?

[image: screenshot of IDE settings]

Comment: Is there any problem with that options?

Comment: I don't need some of them in my platform.